# How to change response data extract in POSTMAN

Tags: json, postman

as in this example, I get the data from Starwar's GraphQL: https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index

Body Request:

```
query {
  allFilms {
    films {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Response data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "allFilms": {
            "films": [
                {
                    "title": "A New Hope"
                },
                {
                    "title": "The Empire Strikes Back"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Return of the Jedi"
                },
                {
                    "title": "The Phantom Menace"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Attack of the Clones"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Revenge of the Sith"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

However, **I want to get the responding data as an array of "films"** like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "A New Hope"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Empire Strikes Back"
  },
  {
    "title": "Return of the Jedi"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Phantom Menace"
  },
  {
    "title": "Attack of the Clones"
  },
  {
    "title": "Revenge of the Sith"
  }
]
```

So how can I do that? *(if I'm not wrong, it's related to `Pre-request Script`)*

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the format of the response, but you can process the result so it provides exactly what you want. I created [this request on Postman](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/request/19391207-d95cf7d2-a82f-4455-8d31-cc1d9021419a) so you can see how I've done it.

You need to transform the response when you fetch it, in postman you would do so in the Tests tab (i.e. post-response script vs pre-request):

```js
// Getting the response data into a variable response
const response = pm.response.json();

// Converting the original response to the format you want
const filmArray = response.data.allFilms.films 

// Logging it to the console so you can verify the results
console.log(filmArray)
```

This is the result of that `console.log` on postman:

[image]

Comment: Could you pls give me script to put in "Pre-request Script"?

Comment: There's no scrip on the pre-request script. You use pre-request to do something to your request (like passing dynamic data, set state variables), but in this case you're not doing any of that. Like I said, you will not be able to alter the response format until AFTER you get it.